# Change default io-wizard images in an Eclipse RCP 3.x application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to change the default images of the import and export wizards in an Eclipse 3.x application? I do not mean the wizard image which can be configured in the wizard extension point but images in the surrounding wizard that shows up when calling for example:

```
IHandlerService service = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                            .getService(IHandlerService.class);
service.executeCommand(ActionFactory.IMPORT.getCommandId(), null);
```

There is an extension point for changing the default images for standard commands (save, save as, delete etc.): [org.eclipse.ui.commandImages](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_commandImages.html). However, I did not found something similar for the images in the import and export dialog (wizard and category icons)

(The application is an Eclipse 3.x RCP application running on Eclipse 4.4 using the compatibility layer.)

Thank you,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure which images you mean. For the large images at the top of the wizard there is no support for this.

The Import/Export wizard (`org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ImportExportWizard`) gets the images from `org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchImages`.

The paths in `WorkbenchImages` are hard coded to be in the `icons` directory of the `org.eclipse.ui` plugin.

The images in the tree part of the wizard come from the individual import/export wizard extension point declaration.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The images that are declared in 
`org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchImages` are the ones I wanted to change. As there is no official method to change them I set your answer as accepted. However, it seems to be possible via the internal API (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

As described in the accepted answer there is no official method to do this but it
is possible via the `declareImage` of the internal class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchImages`.

In my `initialize` of my `WorkbenchAdvisor` I replaced the shared images in the following way:

```
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class MyWorkbenchAdvisor extends WorkbenchAdvisor {
  ...      
  @Override
  public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer conf) {
    ...
    try {
      // wizard icon
      WorkbenchImages.declareImage(
              IWorkbenchGraphicConstants.IMG_WIZBAN_IMPORT_WIZ,
              <get image descriptor>, true);  
      // folder icon                  
      WorkbenchImages.declareImage(
              ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_FOLDER,
              <get image descriptor>, true);
    }...
```

This can break with every Eclipse version because I access the internal API but
it solved the problem for me.